# Rendering ndb model property in <select> drop down using WTForms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

[image]

When I render the form the entire ndb model (`PartModel` is coming through. I'd like to have it render only the `part_number` property, but actual store the `PartModel`. I've dug through the WTForms documentation and I'm having a tough time figuring out the right way to do this.

Any thoughts? Relevant files are shown below.

*new_dimension.html*

```
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label">{{ form.dimension_part.label }}</div>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form.dimension_part|safe }}
                    {% if form.dimension_part.errors %}
                    <ul class="errors">
                        {% for error in form.dimension_part.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

*views.py*

```
def list_dimensions(part_id=None):
    """List dimensions"""
    if part_id is not None:
        print "************Part ID is",part_id
        Part = PartModel.get_by_id(part_id)
        dimensions = DimensionModel.query(DimensionModel.dimension_part==Part.key).fetch() 
        title = "Dimensions for {}".format(Part.part_name)
    else:
        dimensions = DimensionModel.query() #creates Query object
        title = "All Dimensions"
    form = DimensionForm() #pulls in DimensionForm
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dimension = DimensionModel(
            dimension_part=form.dimension_part.data.key,
            dimension_name=form.dimension_name.data,
            dimension_value=form.dimension_value.data,
            dimension_usl = form.dimension_usl.data,
            dimension_lsl = form.dimension_lsl.data,
            added_by=users.get_current_user()
        )
        try:
            dimension.put()
            dimension_id = dimension.key.id()
            flash(u'Dimension %s successfully saved.' % dimension_id, 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('list_dimensions'))
        except CapabilityDisabledError:
            flash(u'App Engine Datastore is currently in read-only mode.', 'info')
            return redirect(url_for('list_dimensions'))
    return render_template('list_dimensions.html', dimensions=dimensions, form=form,title=title) #pushes query object into template
```

*forms.py*

```
PartForm = model_form(PartModel, wtf.Form, field_args={
    'part_name': dict(validators=[validators.Required()]),
    'part_number': dict(validators=[validators.Required()])
})
```

*models.py*

```
class PartModel(ndb.Model):
    """Part"""
    part_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    part_number = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    added_by = ndb.UserProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class DimensionModel(ndb.Model):
    """Dimension"""
    dimension_part = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True,kind=PartModel)
    dimension_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    dimension_value = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    dimension_usl = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    dimension_lsl = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    added_by = ndb.UserProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{ form.dimension_part.part_number | safe }}`?

Comment: I have, it just eliminates the input field completely (no select, no text box, etc.)